# Python findall regex does not work

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to find all the variables in a perl code. 
The variables look like : `$variable_test`. 
So here is the regex I use : `^\$\w+$`
This gives me this line in Python :

`match = re.findall(r'^\$\w+$',line)`

It works, except when the variable is surrounded by special characters such as `',",\,/` and I don't understand why. So for a variable like `/"$test` for example, there will be no match. I can't figure out why it is happening and how to solve the problem.

Thank you for your help

Comment: It might turn out a bit more complex, see [*The Syntax of Variable Names*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) BTW, why `r'^\$\w+$'` and not `r'\B\$\w+\b'`?

Comment: What your regex is asking for is a line that has nothing but `$variable_test` in it. So it won't match `/"$test`, but it also won't match `$test + 2` or `$test || $other_test` or any other expression or statement besides the useless expression that references a variable and does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first character of your regexp, `'^'` matches the beginning of the string, and the last char of your regexp, `'$'`, matches the end of the string.

So, your regexp only matches strings that consist of the variable name and nothing else.

Change your regexp to `r'\$\w+'`.

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you that's great !